# Why Playground not allowing me to execute the code?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, build, swift-playground

I have tried quit and re-open my xCode, also restart my mac several time but still facing this issue.

Unable to run my code because of this:

[image: Failed to launch process: debugserver is running in translation]

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because of **Rosetta**.
Go to Application -> Xcode -> Get Info -> uncheck Rosetta.
And restart your mac.